# php get input value to title

Tags: php, input, title

I have a form search by using Google Search Engine Custom . Now i wanna to get text value in input name "q" or by id "searchcse" to show in the title .

My form show below

```
<form role="search" action="/search" id="search-cse" method="get">
<input class="searchcse" id="searchcse" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Everything..!.">
<button class="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

Anyone help me !

I have to try by :

```
<?php foreach ($_POST as $searchcse => $value) {
   echo $searchcse;
   echo $value;
} ?>
```

but it don't show !  this my search url : http://google.gaix.info

Comment: the value is passed by name in POST, so in this case you just have to look in `$_POST['q']` (since the name of the input form is q)

Answer (score 0):

You need to get via element name `$q` not the element Id as `$searchcse`.

Comment: Oh yeah ! Thanks @Ariful Haque . it by '<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>' . Now i need to appy by words "-" show in between '<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?> **-** My Site Title' . So, what can i do by php if ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['q']` in your php code. Like,

```
$searchQuery = $_GET['q']; // $searchQuery will have the value input in input element with name q
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks @Venkata Krishna  '<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?>' . So if wanna to put one word (-) show in between: Ex: this key words search - My  Default title . So what ca i do by using the '<?php if ... ;?>'

Comment: You mean to say, you need to concatenate "this key words search" to the searchquery put in the input box ? If my understanding is correct, Check the edited and added PS in the answer.

Comment: I want to the cross (-) show between keywords and titles default display. '<?php echo $_GET['q']; ?> - Home Site Title' [=> Ex: by this title "_php get input value to title - Stack Overflow_"

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code from

> ```
> <?php foreach ($_POST as $searchcse => $value) {
>    echo $searchcse;
>    echo $value;
> } ?>
> ```

to

> ```
> <?php foreach ($_GET as $searchcse => $value) {
>    echo $searchcse;
>    echo $value;
> } ?>
> ```

Because you have used the form method='get'. Also on more option if you will change this method to 'post' than your foreach loop is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To get the query and insert it to the title use the `title` tag in HTML and `$_GET` superglobal in PHP

```
<html><head>
<title><?php echo $_GET['q'];?></title>
</head><body>
.....
<form role="search" action="/search" id="search-cse" method="get">
<input class="searchcse" id="searchcse" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Everything..!.">
<button class="submit" type="submit"></button>
</form>
</body></html>
```